FHIR Patch to add array elements using HAPI and FhirPath
I am using Java and the HAPI FHIR client library to talk to an Azure FHIR endpoint. I am trying to Patch/Add elements to an array that was just created. Ideally I want to append using '-' instead of specifying index (like index 0 and shuffling elements to the right in the array). I am having a problem specifying the Path and Name for the Patch:Add operation using HAPI and FhirPath.
The following function builds the Parameters for the patch operation:
public Parameters buildParameters(Parameters params, String fhirPath, String operationType, String value, String name) {
        Parameters.ParametersParameterComponent op = params.addParameter().setName("operation");
        op.addPart().setName("type").setValue(new StringType(operationType));
        op.addPart().setName("path").setValue(new StringType(fhirPath));
        op.addPart().setName("value").setValue(new StringType(value));
        op.addPart().setName("name").setValue((new StringType(name)));
        return params;
    }

The following code builds the Parameters for establishing an empty array and the patch operation is a success when you add it to a Bundle and execute():
> parameters = buildParameters(parameters,resource.getResourceType().name()+".meta","add","","security");

Here is an example JSON patch used in the example below where we want to add an element to the new array (a String constant that is named ADD_SSP_BODY in the Java code below):
{
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "name": "operation",
      "part": [
        {
          "name": "type",
          "valueCode": "add"
        },
        {
          "name": "path",
          "valueString": "meta"
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "valueString": "security"
        },
        {
          "name": "value",
          "valueCoding": {
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActCode",
            "code": "SSP",
            "display": "sensitive service provider information sensitivity"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The following code lines are attempts to add this element to the new array but I am getting errors:
String message = 
         Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ADD_SSP_BODY.getBytes());

    //parse error on '-'

         parameters = buildParameters(parameters,resource.getResourceType().name()+".meta.security","add",message,"(-)");
        
       // OR

         parameters = buildParameters(parameters,resource.getResourceType().name()+".meta.security","add",message,"-");


     //element already exists error at index 0
    
     parameters = buildParameters(parameters,resource.getResourceType().name()+".meta.security","add",message,"(0)");
    
     //OR
    
     parameters = buildParameters(parameters,resource.getResourceType().name()+".meta.security","add",message,"0");

Can someone assist with values for fhir Path and Name to do successful addition of elements?
